# Make PHP overwrite XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I want when someone hits 'submit' on a form to then open an xml file and overwrite all of it's contents with new data generate from the form.

Can PHP do that? What should I look for to start? Any examples?

Comment: `file_put_contents('yourfile.xml', $_POST['the_new_xml'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using

- [fwrite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

  ```
  $toWrite; // data generated from form, formatted to XML
  $fp = fopen('data.xml', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $toWrite);
  fclose($fp);
  ```

Comment: @Phoenix You're right; fixed. I wasn't as thorough in my answers a year ago as I am today ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are just getting started.
 
You need to research the following:

1. POST requests
2. File operations in PHP

Also, if you have a php specific question, distill it down to a word and add it at the end of php.net/ 

For example, try going to php.net/xml (you will find documentation on working with XML)

Also, whoever modded the original poster down - cmon, man. If you think it's too base of a question just move on. We all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Have the form to fill the datas
2 - Send the data of the form to an action page (it can be the same page if you wish)
3 - Write to an XML file the datas from the form.
4 - It is done!

I do not understood why you need to exchange the data. 
Is much easy you just create a new XML file with the data you wish. 
Take a look at this sample below.

```
    // YOUR DATA FROM METHOD POST OR GET
       $doc1 = $_POST['doc1'];
       ... and so on 


    // Start XML file, echo parent node
       $data = '<sistema versao="1.02" encoding="utf-8">';

    // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE


  $data .=  '<dest>';
      $data .=  '<doc>' . parseToXML($doc1) . '</doc>';
      $data .=  '<xName>' . parseToXML($name) . '</xName>';
      $data .=  '<addrDest>';
        $data .=  '<xLgr>' . parseToXML($addr) . '</xLgr>';
        $data .=  '<nro>' . parseToXML($num) . '</nro>';
        $data .=  '<xCpl>' . parseToXML($comp) . '</xCpl>';
        $data .=  '<xSub>' . parseToXML($suburb) . '</xSub>';
        $data .=  '<cMun>3523206</cMun>';
        $data .=  '<xMun>' . parseToXML($city) . '</xMun>';
        $data .=  '<UF>' . parseToXML($state) . '</UF>';
        $data .=  '<CEP>' . parseToXML($zip) . '</CEP>';
        $data .=  '<cCoun>1058</cCoun>';
        $data .=  '<xCoun>BRASIL</xCoun>';
        $data .=  '<phone>' . parseToXML($tel1) . '</phone>';
      $data .=  '</addrDest>';
      $data .=  '<email>' . parseToXML($email) . '</email>';
      $data .=  '</dest>';


        // End XML file
        $data .=  '</sistema>';


        # Put data into client.xml 
        file_put_contents('client.xml', $data);
```

I hope this give a start to you. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

This looks answered already, but the fwrite() resolution doesn't really explain how it works for us novices. I used file_put_contents instead, but here is a working example...

```
$writeXML = new XMLWriter();
$writeXML->openMemory();
$writeXML->setIndent(true);
$writeXML->startDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$writeXML->startElement($root);

//foreach loop iterating through array results and writing elements

$writeXML->endDocument();
//this will overwrite the xml file
file_put_contents('xmlfile.xml', $writeXML->flush(true));
//this will append any data to the end of the file
file_put_contents('xmlfile.xml', $writeXML->flush(true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Hope this helps... file_put_contents: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).